# How do I compare a .txt to another and return what is not in it?

Tags: python

I am trying to compare a .txt file to another and return what is not in it.

For example

**one.txt**

```
a
b
c
d
```

**two.txt**

```
b
c
d
e
```

**output**

```
e
```

I have tried using symmetric_difference() but this will return the difference between both of them. Using the example, it will return e and a.

```
with open('text_one.txt', 'r') as file1:
    with open('text_two.txt', 'r') as file2:
        same = set(file1).symmetric_difference(file2)

same.discard('\n')

with open('output.txt', 'w') as file_out:
    for line in same:
        file_out.write(line)
```

Comment: Take a look at this https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html

Comment: "I have tried using symmetric_difference() but this will return the difference between both of them." Well... what do you think `symmetric` indicates, in the name `symmetric_difference`? Did you try looking through the documentation of the other `set` functionality, to see if something else matches what you want?

Answer (score 2):

If you want the items of file2 that are not in file1,just replace this:

```
same = set(file1).symmetric_difference(file2)
```

by this:

```
same = set(file2)-set(file1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should take care of `newline` characters before comparing the sets of lines to avoid unexpected output if an equal line is the last item in one file. `b difference a` will return only the missing items in `a`.

```
strip = lambda x: x.strip()
with open('one.txt') as f1, open('two.txt') as f2, open('output.txt', 'w') as out:
    out.write(
        '\n'.join(
        set(map(strip, f2))
            .difference(map(strip, f1))))
```

For the output I'm assuming you want every missing line as a new line.

**output.txt**

```
e
```